# Error trying to insert a record using PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I keep getting the following errors running a script I am writing and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

The errors:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp64\www\FOLDER\incl\registratie.php on line 21
>   and
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp64\www\FOLDER\incl\registratie.php on line 21
>   I am trying to run this script:

```
<?php
include('dbConnect.php');

$email = 'PLACEHOLDER';
$voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
$achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
$land = $_POST['land'];
$geboortejaar = $_POST['geboortejaar'];
$geslacht = 'PLACEHOLDER';
$betalingsmethode = 'PLACEHOLDER';
$rekeningnummer = $_POST['rekeningnummer'];
$gebruikersnaam = $_POST['gebruikersnaam'];
$wachtwoord = $_POST['wachtwoord'];
$herhaalWachtwoord = $_POST['herhaal-wachtwoord'];
$abonnement = $_POST['abonnement'];

if($wachtwoord === $herhaalWachtwoord){
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(:email, :achternaam, :voornaam, :betalingsmethode, :rekeningnummer, :abonnement, :ab_start, :ab_einde, :gebruikersnaam, :wachtwoord, :land, :geslacht, :geboortejaar)';
    $query = $verbinding -> prepare($sql);
    $query -> execute(array(':email' => $email,
                            ':achternaam' => $achternaam,
                            ':voornaam' => $voornaam,
                            ':betalingsmethode' => $betalingsmethode,
                            ':rekeningnummer' => $rekeningnummer,
                            ':abonnement' => $abonnement,
                            ':ab_start' => date('Y-m-d'),
                            ':ab_einde' => null,
                            ':gebruikersnaam' => $gebruikersnaam,
                            ':wachtwoord' => md5($wachtwoord),
                            ':land' => $land,
                            ':$geslacht' => $geslacht,
                            ':geboortejaar' => null));
    echo 'KLAAR';
}
else {
    echo 'ERROR';
}
?>
```

Comment: `':$geslacht' => $geslacht,` doesn't look correct

Comment: Found the $, getting a different error now. Should I open up a new topic?

Comment: `md5($wachtwoord)` that tells me you're using an unsafe password storage hash. Use `password_hash()` if you value your work and userbase.

Comment: *"Found the $, getting a different error now. Should I open up a new topic?"* - You can edit your post to contain the new code and error. But please DO NOT overwrite your original post/code. Add the new stuff under it and as an **Edit:**............ @R.Doe